# Session is lost for Some Users after redirecting from Payment Gateway Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies, payment-gateway

For some users session is lost after redirecting from Payment Gateway after deploying to IIS 7. It works well on localhost but not working after deploying.
My web config Session State is INPROC and timeout 20 min.
Cookieless= true
For some IP's, Session is getting lost.

Comment: See [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/). Using `InProc` is not recommended for production applications because there is no way to control when an application pool recycle will cause your session state variables to be wiped out. Depending on your requirements, there may be better ways than using session state anyway.

Comment: I have a similar scenario where the payment gateway simply redirects to a return URL that I supply them. Even though it returns to the same website in the same browser window, on return from the payment gateway my session variables are gone. On a different payment gateway, the gateway actually posts data back to my site, then session remains in tact...so I'm bit stumped in this one as well. Did you solve your situation?

Comment: As NightOwl888 states, the most likely reason is that your application pool is recycling, which will kill any in-process sessions. You could switch to persisted sessions, but note that events like Session_End will nolonger fire if you're using those to release stock levels, etc. There are a number of reasons for app pool recycles, including: updated code; too many errors; application has been running for 29 hours (the default).

Comment: Have same problem, after returning from payment some users loose session, I use session state server not inproc, same result

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the paypal payflow gateway.  It worked fine up to a month ago and now this problem.

Comment: Facing a bit of a problem with Cybersource myself . Can you guys have a look at the question that i have posted over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072131/unable-to-persist-cookies-after-redirecting-from-external-url-back-to-action-met).

Comment: For the commenters above who are losing session. This is very possibly caused by 'samesite' 3rd party cookie rules. Depending on how samesite is being set, IIS could very well be treating the postback from the payment gateway as a new session. If your app needs to read from earlier saved session data to continue the transaction it will fail when the new session is created.