# Unable to persist cookies after redirecting from External URL back to Action Method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, cybersource

So as part of the payment process in my site, I have to visit an ExternalURL to validate certain fields and as a result of the Validation completion, I will be getting a POST back to my Action Method with some response variables. The problem that I am facing is that the cookies fail to persist even though I have tried out the following Steps.

1. Have already explicitly assigned the SameSite Flag for the cookie to be Lax.
2. Have already made some changes to the Web.config that I will be including below.

Part of the Web.config that I modified.

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None">
      <forms cookieSameSite="Lax" requireSSL="false" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" executionTimeout="500" />
    
    <!-- Added this line for restoring Cookie values after the redirect to an external URI. -->
    <httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" cookieless="false" timeout="360" />    
  </system.web>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />
      </webServices>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCaching="false" enableCompression="false" />
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <!--<rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=lax" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="No SameSite">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=lax" negate="true" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>-->
  </system.webServer>
```

The method from where we call the External URL has this piece of code.

```
HttpCookie ckpaymentTRID = new HttpCookie("PaResTransactionID");
ckpaymentTRID.Value = resultPaymentObj.TransactionID.ToString();
ckpaymentTRID.SameSite = System.Web.SameSiteMode.Lax;
ckpaymentTRID.Secure = true;

HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(ckpaymentTRID);
```

The method where I receive the POST from the External URL consists of this

```
var SomeCookiee = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["PaResTransactionID"];
```

Also, I have browsed through this article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite) and am aware of the changes pre and post the .NET framework update.

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns all the web.config setting changes were inconsequential as the remaining were actually enough to make the cut. Here is actually how I got a hint about how to solve this issue :

As I was being redirected from my application to the External-URL.....in Google Chrome, under dev tools you get to see the cookies that have been passed... I was always getting a warning saying that "since your cookie is not a **secure** cookie, chrome by default changes the **SameSite** setting from **None** to **Lax** and so your cookie doesn't persist throughout the request at all.".....which then prompted me to change the web application settings to run as https://localhost rather than http://localhost in VS2019. Once I did that, I saw that I no more needed the explicit **HttpCookie** or **sessionState** settings to be modified or in fact placed at all in the web.config and the Cookie value persisted in spite of the External Domain Re-Direction.